# Python-MySQL query does not showing results including the previous import in same query

Tags: python, mysql

I have a function what is adding new records in to Mysql database after scanning a barcode. Function is working but there is a problem with returning result on the App screen.
When I scan the barcode first time it does not return any results even when i can see that the new record was created. But when i scan the barcode second time it returns only 1 record.
Edit:(added more about the issue)
And after that it is always -1 record, which would not be problem i could add +1 to all results but the problem is the first one, as it returns nothing at all.
I tried to use time.sleep(.3) between the queries but that did not have any effect.
I now wonder if the Python code is wrong or my SQL query should be somehow different.

```
def db_execute3(config, sql, val):
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    try:
        mycursor.execute(sql, val)
        mydb.commit()
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.CR_CONN_HOST_ERROR:
            popip.open()
            Clock.schedule_once(popip.dismiss, 3)
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            popx.open()
            Clock.schedule_once(popx.dismiss, 3)
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            popdb.open()
            Clock.schedule_once(popdb.dismiss, 3)
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2:
            popbr.open()
            Clock.schedule_once(popbr.dismiss, 3)
        else:
            mycursor.close()

def inbsort_btndwn(self, _):
   cont = self.container_no.text.upper()
   barc = self.sku_barcode.text.upper()
   sort_worknumb = self.sort_worknumb.text.upper()
   val = (sort_worknumb, cont, barc)
   valx = (cont,barc)
   if barc is "" and cont is "":
       errorsound.play()
       self.pallet_sku.text = ""
       self.number_sku.text = ""
       Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_container_no, 0.2)
   elif barc is "" and cont is not "":
       errorsound.play()
       self.pallet_sku.text = ""
       self.number_sku.text = ""
       Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_sku_barcode, 0.2)
   else:
       try:
           mydb = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
           checkupd = mydb.cursor(prepared=True)
           sqlq = "select * from inb_container where `container_no` = %s and `sku_code` = %s;"
           checkupd.execute(sqlq, valx)
           record = checkupd.fetchone()
           if record is None:
               errorsound.play()
               popuni.content.text = "No records for scanned Barcode!"
               popuni.open()
               Clock.schedule_once(popuni.dismiss, 2)
               Clock.schedule_once(self.clear_barcode, .2)
               Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_sku_barcode, 0.21)
           else:
               correctsound.play()
               sql = "INSERT INTO inb_sor_con (`work_number`, `container_no`,`sku_barcode`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
               db_execute3(config, sql, val)

               sqlz = "SELECT ic.sort_box,ic.sort_pallet FROM inb_container ic, " \
                      "inb_sor_con ib WHERE ic.container_no =ib.container_no and ic.sku_code = ib.sku_barcode " \
                      "and ic.container_no = %s and ic.sku_code = %s"
               valz = (cont, barc)
               checkupd.execute(sqlz, valz) #v289-ukan1012044-n10 #msku8416005
               myresult = checkupd.fetchall()
               for row in myresult:
                   xxx = "Scanned: {} of: {}".format(checkupd.rowcount, row[0])
                   zzz = "{}".format(row[1])

                   self.pallet_sku.text = zzz
                   self.number_sku.text = xxx
               Clock.schedule_once(self.clear_barcode, 0.2)
               Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_sku_barcode, 0.21)

       except mysql.connector.Error as err:
           print(err.errno)
           pass
```

This is the database:

```
create table inb_container(
`container_no` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`sku_code` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`sort_box` int(5),
`sort_pcs` int(6),
`sort_pallet` varchar(3),
Unique (container_no,sku_code)
);
create table inb_sor_con(
`id_scan` int(6) auto_increment not null primary key,
`work_number` varchar(12),
`container_no` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`sku_barcode` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`sort_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
FOREIGN KEY (work_number) REFERENCES user_logins(work_number),
FOREIGN KEY (container_no) REFERENCES inb_container(container_no));
```

Comment: To begin with, don't use `is` for comparisons; use `==`.

Comment: Your code could also made clearer by not mixing what I assume to be UI code (`popuni`, `popb`, ...) with the database logic.

Comment: @AKX well none of those things has any inpact on the results, unfortunatelly. popuni,popb are just popups for error massage, not important.
Maybe can i somehow combine INSERT Statement with Select statement so it will first insert in to table data and then it will makes the Select part for returning results, instead of two statements?

Comment: Well, if the SELECT query does return multiple rows, you're looping over them and only the last result will end up being shown.

Comment: @AKX it returns all records except the one I just inserted at same time I ask for Select statement, I need to somehow make it i think first insert then do select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, I'd suggest refactoring your code so it's not mixing UI code with database access. That way you can more easily test each bit of your program (either manually, from a separate module) or automatically using unit tests or such.

You can also freely create new cursors, don't reuse a single one.

Here's one such refactoring...

```
def find_container(db, *, container_no, barcode):
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "select * from inb_container where `container_no` = %s and `sku_code` = %s",
        (container_no, barcode),
    )
    return cursor.fetchone()


def insert_sor_con(db, *, sort_worknumb, container_no, barcode):
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "INSERT INTO inb_sor_con (`work_number`, `container_no`,`sku_barcode`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
        (sort_worknumb, container_no, barcode),
    )
    db.commit()


def get_scan_results(db, *, container_no, barcode):
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        """
    SELECT ic.sort_box,ic.sort_pallet
    FROM inb_container ic, inb_sor_con ib
    WHERE (
        ic.container_no = ib.container_no AND
        ic.sku_code = ib.sku_barcode AND
        ic.container_no = %s AND
        ic.sku_code = %s
    )""",
        (container_no, barcode),
    )
    return cursor.fetchall()


def show_error(message):
    errorsound.play()
    popuni.content.text = message
    popuni.open()
    Clock.schedule_once(popuni.dismiss, 2)


class SomeUI:
    def inbsort_btndwn(self, _):
        container_no = self.container_no.text.upper()
        barcode = self.sku_barcode.text.upper()
        sort_worknumb = self.sort_worknumb.text.upper()
        if not (barcode and container_no):
            errorsound.play()
            self.pallet_sku.text = ""
            self.number_sku.text = ""
            if not barcode:
                Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_sku_barcode, 0.2)
            else:
                Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_container_no, 0.2)
            return

        try:
            with mysql.connector.connect(**config) as mydb:
                container_record = find_container(
                    mydb, container_no=container_no, barcode=barcode
                )
                if container_record:
                    correctsound.play()
                    insert_sor_con(
                        mydb,
                        sort_worknumb=sort_worknumb,
                        container_no=container_no,
                        barcode=barcode,
                    )
                    scan_results = list(
                        get_scan_results(mydb, container_no=container_no, barcode=barcode)
                    )
                    for sort_box, sort_pallet in scan_results:
                        self.pallet_sku.text = "{}".format(sort_pallet)
                        self.number_sku.text = "Scanned: {} of: {}".format(
                            len(scan_results), sort_box
                        )
                else:
                    show_error("No records for scanned Barcode!")
        except Exception as exc:
            # may want to use `traceback.print_traceback()` here for more detail
            print(exc)
            show_error(f"Error: {exc}")
        Clock.schedule_once(self.clear_barcode, 0.2)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_sku_barcode, 0.21)
```

Comment: Yes this one works exactly as it was planned.
I know I have still much to learn, if you seen my code you would kill me :D my code looks nothing like this, but is working :{